# Exception occurred processing WSGI script SyntaxError from item-catalog import app as application

Tags: python, apache, wsgi

I am getting an internal server error after trying to set up my python project with apache. There's something wrong with this line SyntaxError:

```
from item-catalog import app as application
```

But if I change it to this, it also doesn't work.

```
import app as application
```

work. My folder structure is

```
/var/www/html/itemcatalog/item-catalog
```

This is my itemcatalog.wsgi file

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/html/itemcatalog")

from item-catalog import app as application
application.secret_key = 'kGTdasfdasfdsa'
```

This is the apache error log:

```
   [Tue Dec 13 02:12:09.149063 2016] [:error] [pid 29155:tid 139672369694464] [client 108.49.103.204:53087] mod_wsgi (pid=29155): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/itemcatalog/item-catalog/itemcatalog.wsgi'.
[Tue Dec 13 02:12:09.149155 2016] [:error] [pid 29155:tid 139672369694464] [client 108.49.103.204:53087]   File "/var/www/html/itemcatalog/item-catalog/itemcatalog.wsgi", line 7
[Tue Dec 13 02:12:09.149202 2016] [:error] [pid 29155:tid 139672369694464] [client 108.49.103.204:53087]     from item-catalog import app as application
[Tue Dec 13 02:12:09.149244 2016] [:error] [pid 29155:tid 139672369694464] [client 108.49.103.204:53087]              ^
[Tue Dec 13 02:12:09.149283 2016] [:error] [pid 29155:tid 139672369694464] [client 108.49.103.204:53087] SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python module names cannot have hyphens in them